# If $Y$ is closed subspace of $X$, then $(Y^*)_*=Y$

Tags: functional-analysis

Exercise says if $Y$ is closed subspace of $X$, then $(Y^*)_*=Y$, where I mean $Y^*$ is set of bounded linear functional on $X$ vanishing on $Y$ and for a subset $F$ of $X^*$(bounded linear functionals on $X$), $F_*=\{x\in X/f(x)=0, \forall f\in F\}$. I got  the containment $(Y^*)_*\supset Y$ but not getting the other side. Any hint. Thanks.

Comment: A more general fact ... if $A$ is any subset of $X$, then $(A^*)_*$ is the closed linear span of $A$.

Comment: This is a special case of the Bipolar theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that $y\notin Y$, there is a $x^{\ast}\in X^{\ast}$ such that $x^{\ast}(y)\ne 0$, this follows by Hahn-Banach by looking at the map $x+\alpha y\rightarrow\alpha\text{dist}(y,Y)$ for $x\in Y$.

Comment: You need $x^{*}=0$ on $Y$.

Comment: This does not answer  the question.

Answer (score 0):

By Hahn Banach Theorem if $x \notin Y$ then there exists $x^{*} \in X^{*}$ such that $x^{*}(x)\neq 0$ but $x^{*}(y)=0$ for all $y \in Y$.   Can you complete the proof using this?

Comment: Yes..proof will follow using contrapositive argument...